# How to read in and parse an XML file on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, xml, web-services

I have a web server which returns an XML file. Lets say http://www.foo.bar/foo.php?wantXML=1

How would I fetch that file from the server and then parse it to access the data? I guess I would have to spawn a new thread and do the whole thing in the background to not block the UI? What classes must I look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SeismicXML sample](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SeismicXML/index.html) from Apple is exaclty what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to do:

- String manipulations
- XPATH

Id opt for xpath in all but the most simple cases - and even in those, you can't argue against xpath. Im not sure of the libraries though, but I know libXML is written in C and supported on the iphone.

For string manipulations, you can use the NS* family of methods.(substringFromIndex, substringToIndex, etc)
And don't forget: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Big Nerd Ranch, 'Parsing XML in Cocoa': http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48

Comment: Even suggesting string manipulation makes me cringe. That's a terrible idea. ;-) TouchXML is the way to go. I respect Aaron Hillegasse and his suggestion of using NSXMLParser as it is fast, but TouchXML is pretty fast and handles most XML data sources handily. Its great because it is an exact implementation of the NSXMLDocument and related classes on OS X. You can use the NSXMLDocument docs to figure out how to use TouchXML because of this relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I've used two approaches:  NSXMLParser for simple and small files, and libxml for larger files.  But there are libraries such as TouchXML that can simplify the process as well.

Basically, if you have a small data set, in memory DOM processing can work fine.  But in a device such as the iPhone, you're better off using SAX-based parsers such as libxml2.

When you need to load the data:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(LoadYourData) withObject:nil];
```

will not block the main UI thread.

For libxml2, you will need to implement C callbacks to process the chunks of data coming in from a NSURLConnection.

Comment: From Jonathan Wight, hosted at Google Code, yes.  Hmm, last time I looked at it was last summer, which looks like the last time it was updated.  But the OS hasn't changed since then either...

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by outdated, but if you mean has it been around a while, then the answer is yes. The point though is that it's a great library that makes XML parsing tasks simple. I like it much better than NSXMLParser, myself and I'm not aware of any 'new' libraries that do a better job.

Comment: Ah, good points. I was under the impression that NSXMLParser was easier to work with. Guess I'll have to look at touchXML again.

Answer (score 1):

To pull down XML or other stuff over http I recommend looking into using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Feel free to have a look at my convenient classes I created to parse simple XML documents like you can get from Nike+. [Link](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/10/31/The-XML-Runner.html)

Basically the usage is as follows

```
NameValueParser *parser = [NameValueParser parser];
[parser addFieldName:@"screenName"]; // Name
[parser addFieldName:@"rank"];       // Position
[parser addFieldName:@"progress"];   // Distance
[parser parseData:data];

NSLog(@"%@", [parser list]); // Lets see what we got
```