# How to Read Parse XML in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode

What framework I should use to grab XML from a http and parse that?

Comment: Can't believe this question still gets asked at least once a week.

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237757/cocoa-objective-c-best-practice-to-parse-xml-document) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729514/sending-and-receiving-xml-to-and-from-server-using-cocoa) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone-how-do-i-use-it-given-a-xml-file-newb-here) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731453/parsing-xml-in-cocoa) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731594/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274513/) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcocoa%5D+xml+file+parse)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read in and parse an XML file on the iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097631/how-to-read-in-and-parse-an-xml-file-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can use the initWithContentsOfURL initializer to actually load the document from the HTTP source.

Answer (score 1):

Try touchXML:

> TouchXML is a lightweight replacement
>   for Cocoa's NSXML* cluster of classes.
>   It is based on the commonly available
>   Open Source libxml2 library.

[Here](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/) is a nice tutorial.

Source has moved a bit, can be found [here](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML)